Как сделать фильтр для каждой ветки в репозитории git?
Сейчас есть репозиторий, в котором ведутся работы по компоненту (компонент написан на C++). Этот компонент используется во многих проектах, и везде он отличается (где-то больше, где-то меньше).
Моя идея такова: создать ветки от master для каждого проекта, делать коммиты только в master, а для каждой ветки написать фильтр, который будет фильтровать каталоги и файлы при обновлении ветки с master, которые нужны именно для данного проекта.
Вопрос заключается в том, что можно ли это реализовать? Я читал про команду git filter-branch с различными префиксами, но не до конца понял, как это реализовать с помощью этой команды, и можно ли вообще.
Буду рад любой помощи: статьи, другие предложения по реализации и т. д.

А не проще ли сделать этот компонент а-ля вендорным, записать в композер и устанавливать как зависимость, а потом в каждом проекте просто подпиливать его под себя.... например через наследование нужных классов или через адаптер или другими вещами....

Потому что по факту, компонент ничего не должен знать про какие-то там проекты (тем более которые могут быть приватными и другие не должны знать об этом тоже). А вот другие проекты могут знать о компоненте

Я На автомате написал про композер)) Короч, нужен какой-то оркестратор или что-то, что подтягивает компонент в проект, как вендорный, сторонний. А потом работа ведётся с ним в рамках проекта

Была такая мысль, и на данный момент она всё-таки как запасная. Потому что хочется упростить максимально данный компонент и подогнать максимально близко для каждого проекта. Но сама идея создания классов-наследников, которые расширяют или переопределяют поведение родительских классов в компоненте есть. Так что да - это как запасной вариант

Это должен быть основным планом, на самом деле, потому что это правильный путь. Во-первых - это потому, что я уже написал во втором комментарии, а во-вторых - представьте, что это не ваш компонент личный, а он чей-то, в каком-то другом репозитории. Что вы бы сделали? Пошли бы по "запасному пути". Так что другое не стОит рассматривать

Хорошо, я вас понял, спасибо.

Кроме классов-наследников есть еще множество вариантов обеспечения вариативности кода, как то условная компиляция, предоставление точек кастомизации и т.п.

По вопросу у меня ощущение, что ты творишь какую-то дичь, но всё же это возможно и даже несколькими способами. Рыть надо в сторону git merge strategies - либо писать свою, либо использовать по файлам ours и theirs, но вообще, тут надо проверять. Можно ещё посмотреть на checkout папок с флагом force.
